# JavaFX decoupling event handling and logic from controller

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

I want to know how to structure JavaFX application espicially, event handling
I need a way to process event outside a Javafx controller.

Let's Suppose that i have:

a person.fxml file with code

and PersonController that controlls that file

```
 public PersonController implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private TextField textField1 ; 

@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


    }

}
```

i want make some thing like

```
public class EventHandler  {
// Process all the person.fxml and PersonController logic her
}
```

So, how i can acheive that so, the PersonController can be stupid.

Comment: What benefit do you expect from this? Usually the controller is part of the P in [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter).

Comment: What are you actually going to do in `PersonController` if you move all the event handling elsewhere?

Comment: I want only set nodes properties, intialize nodes .

Comment: Well, you could define the event handlers separately in a [script file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#scripting), but perhaps that is not what you want to do.

Comment: I want to benefit from design pattern  like Event bus and Dpendency injection.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Event bus, but for Dependency Injection there's no reason you would need to split initialization from event handling in order to use that pattern. Just use D.I. directly in the controller as it stands without factoring the event handling into a separate class. It's hard for me to imagine that you could implement event bus similarly. And if you do want to move initialization elsewhere, you can do (almost?) all initialization in the FXML. Then `PersonController` just becomes your `EventHandler` class.

Comment: That should have read "It's hard for me to imagine that you *couldn't* implement event bus similarly".

Comment: I just read about this two mechanisms, but i don't really know if they are useful.